# Trouble Implementing Stashy flyout

Tags: jquery, flyout

I'm trying to implement Stashy flyout (http://stashy.azurewebsites.net/flyout/javascript) and as a bit of a jquery newbie I'm missing something. Here is my very simple page. I'm just trying to get it to work and then I will implement on a WP installation. I'm probably missing something really basic...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/Stashy.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.hammer.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Stashy.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 </head>

 <body>

 <div class="st-flyout">
    <div class="st-flyout-container">
        <div class="st-flyout-menu">
            ... Menu content ...
        </div>
        <div class="st-flyout-main">
            ... Content ...
            <a href="#" class="st-flyout-toggle"></a>
            ... Place the toggle button wherever you want ...
            ... More content ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <h1>Fly out test</h1>
    <img src="cool-cat.jpg" />
</div>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                var flyout1 = Stashy.Flyout(".st-flyout", { slideType : "push", enableTouch : true }).layout();             
            });
        </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope. Just the div st-flyout content appears at the top of the page.

Comment: I've created a fiddle with the same code: http://jsfiddle.net/robahas/f649c9k3/1/